# How may I associate fields of the billing information commerce profile with profile2 fields?

Tags: commerce, users

How may I associate fields of the billing information commerce profile with profile2 fields?

I´ve got this billing information profile, where I´ve added a "username", "password" and "telephone" fields.

Those are named:

> field_c_username
>
> field_c_pass
>
> field_c_telephone

I need:

**use case 1:** `field_c_username` and `field_c_pass` to remain hidden in the form, so I can manually set them when reviewing the order.

**use case 2**: And `field_c_telephone` to get copied to the field_profile_telephone inside the profile2 user profile.

I´ve installed **commerce_profile2 module** but not only I didn´t understand how it worked (I thought that it would add some profile fields into the commerce profile, but it didn´t), but I don´t know if it works in use case 1.

How may I do that?
Thanks for your insight!

UPDATE: I´ve read [this explanation](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/custom-commerce-checkout-panes) saying that´s actually possible (specially [this comment](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/custom-commerce-checkout-panes#comment-2167)), but as I´m not a developer I can´t quite understand how to actually put there all profile2 fields and after creating a new user (the customer) to take that information and insert it into the profile2 fields of the newly created user.